# Using character sets with letter 'a' in them are resulting in unexpected behavior within certain directories

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

We have some scripts that parse a list of strings using `echo $VALUE | tr -d [:space:]` which have been working fine in their original directory. However, we later found out that there is a different directory that we're supposed to keep these scripts in so we thought no big deal and moved them over. However, after moving them over we noticed that our output was getting all messed up because the spaces were no longer being removed. Instead, the character 'a' was the only thing being removed.

After some trial and error we found that character sets that contained the letter 'a' such as in

```
[:alnum:]  
[:alpha:]  
[:blank:]  
[:graph:]
[:space:]
```

Were just being substituted for 'a'. So running `echo $VALUE | tr -d [:space:]` was actually just removing the letter 'a'. Example: `echo "t a r g e t" | tr -d [:space:]` would return `t  r g e t` instead of `target`. To confirm this I executed `echo [:space:]` in the shell and it simply returned `a`. How does something like this work? Is there a way I can reverse this?

Comment: What is your locale? Run the command `locale`

Comment: BTW, `echo $VALUE` is itself buggy and needs to be `echo "$VALUE"` (or, better, `printf '%s\n' "$VALUE"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) (covering the main lack-of-quotes issue), and also the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX `echo` spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) (explaining the advice to use `printf` instead).

Comment: Do you have a file named `a`? You might have to use `tr -d '[:space:]'`

Comment: @Bodo yeah that was the issue, I had a file named `a` and I wasn't enclosing in quotes so it was globbing that file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe happens if the current directory contains a file called `a`.

To see what happens, run these commands:

```
echo [:space:]
echo "[:space:]"
echo '[:space:]'
```

When brackets are not enclosed in quotes, they expands to the list of files they match. Search for "shell file globbing" to learn about all the rules. In this case that would be the following files:

```
:
s
p
a
c
e
```

If only the file `a` exists in the current directory, the first echo command will expand to that.

When you create the files `p` and `e` in that directory as well, the first echo command will output `a e p`.

The takeaway is: always enclose strings in quotes when programming in the shell.

Comment: You'd be on quite solid ground to strengthen this from "my guess is that" to "this will happen if"

Comment: Oh you're right, it looks like there is a file called `a` in the directory. I'd tested and confirmed that enclosing in quotes caused the expected behavior but I didn't know why that was. I assumed it had something to do with `[:space:]` getting substituted for `a` but I didn't know that it was because there was a file called `a`! Thank you so much!